# Looking for confirmation of how to use React i18n

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am researching options for integrating language translation into a web app. I am comparing Google Translations API and React i18n right now, and it seems like i18n requires you to manually add all translations yourself - as in getting ahold of the translation for every page and adding that into the json data for the translation file.

**I am just looking for confirmation that that is the way i18n works, and that I am not misunderstanding anything.**

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to answer my own question. In case anyone else has the same question, the answer is yes: it does require manual translation for the entire site.